# Georeferencing raster using world file in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing, world-file

I have downloaded a raster (jpg) and associated world file (jpgw) from https://qimagery.information.qld.gov.au

I have turned on the option in ArcMap to use the world file to define the coordinates of the raster.

When I bring the file into ArcMap I get the warning that there is an unknown spatial reference.

I have tried editing the spatial reference for the raster in ArcCatalog for the file for a number of common protections used in Australia. I always get the same error. Perhaps I'm just tried the wrong coordinate systems?

Interestingly, when I bring in a raster and world file sourced from nearmap instead, it locates the image in the correct place, without me having the set a spatial reference for the raster, but still gives the "unknown spatial reference" warning.

I've attached the image and world file I'm having trouble with under the following links:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GjeBcFDQmH7coYJtq7CQlZdB9TgzJmeI?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to define your projection. Data Management Tools \ Projections and Transformations \ Raster \ Define projection

Comment: Thanks for the response @GeoGyro, this creates a JGw file but still doesn't properly locate the image. I've tried using a range of projections but keep having the same issue as originally described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had this same issue, I am using QGIS but it should work the same (i loaded your files and they work). Make sure your world file and jpeg are in the same folder, load into Arcmap and set the projection to EPSG:3857, WGS 84/ Pseudo Mercator. That should then project correctly

Comment: Thank you Emily! 3857 does indeed seem to be the correct projection for the image! 

It still wasn't working for me though. I then realised that when I was changing the spatial reference in arcCatalog, it wasn't actually saving any changes. I therefore imported the raster into a GDB, then updated the spatial reference to 3857. This then saved and the raster appeared in the right place the next time I imported it.